# Enable dongleless bluetooth on windows7 virtualbox guest

Tags: virtualbox, bluetooth

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 with windows 7 as a guest on virtualbox 5.40.    I'd like to allow the windows guest to see a bluetooth microphone/headset which *does not* have a dongle.     My understanding is that the way to pair in windows is  Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Add a Device.    And windows is supposed to find any nearby bluetooth device that's in pairing mode.

But no device is recognized.

I've tried this both with bluetooth enabled and disabled on the host.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

As per request here's the output from lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 13fe:5500 Kingston Technology Company Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 048: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1bcf:2b91 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 021: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: If your BT device is connected with USB, you can pass it through to the guest.

Comment: Please add output of `lsusb` to your question. Built-in BT adapters are very often connected by USB.

Comment: No USB is involved at all.   For example, I have a  bluetooth headset that I pair directly with ubuntu's internal bluetooth

Comment: The internal bluetooth most likely is connected by USB.

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6, I've added the output of `lsusb` to my question

Comment: What is VB 5.40? Is it 5.0.40?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bluetooth adapter is connected by USB. It is

```
8087:0a2b Intel Corp.
```

You can pass it to the guest system using VirtualBox Device menu.

You need to have the Extension Pack installed.

If you pass the BT device to the guest system it won't be available for the host system.